# Insert Query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, apriori

I have this table `TAB`

```
ID | Trans
------------
1  | 99
2  | 99
3  | 99
2  | 90
4  | 22
4  | 22
2  | 99
2  | 90
```

I want to get the count of trans that appear together for a single id, for eg, '1 has 90 & 99' and '2 has 90 & 99' in the entire table so the count is 2. This is similar to Apriori Algorithm's Third Step.

I tried this but didn't work-

```
select 
    count(trans) 
from 
    Tab 
where 
    trans = 99 & 90  
group by 
    ID 
having 
    ID = 2
```

My expected ans for Trans- 90 & 99 is

Trans1 | Trans2 | Support
    ------------

90  | 99    |  1

I also want to insert this into a new table.

Comment: What would be the expected result?

Comment: Please also try to find a more appropriate title for your question. From what I see, it has nothing to do with an insert.

Comment: Why "Insert query"? There's no `INSERT` anywhere to be seen .....

Comment: Am I the only one here that didn't understand the question at all?

Comment: @Jens: why should an ID be unique? That could be a foreign key to a different table (e.g. a 1:many relationship).

Comment: This is just a small model of the problem that I am trying to solve.  I have to insert the answer into another table.  Sorry for not mentioning it.

Comment: @marc_s I want to insert it into a table. Sorry.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Try again, Ive reformatted the question. I hope this will help you help me

Comment: Sorry, still not very clear. do you want to get the number of rows that contains the same value in the ID and 2 different values in the TRANS column? can you post your desired outcome?

Comment: @ZoharPeled For every Id that has both the transaction increase one count.

Comment: so you want the result to be the number of values in 'Trans' column for each value in 'Id' column where there are at least 2 different values in the 'Trans' column?

Comment: @ZoharPeled not different values but specific values..  Kindly refer my desired result table.  Thanks for the effort

Comment: try to change the condition in your sql to "where trans IN(99, 90)"

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you can use `SUM(CASE WHEN...END)` for this:

```
DECLARE 
    @trans1 INT = 99,
    @trans2 INT = 90

SELECT
    ID,
    PairCount =
        CASE 
            WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Trans = @trans1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= SUM(CASE WHEN Trans = @trans2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                THEN SUM(CASE WHEN Trans = @trans2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            ELSE SUM(CASE WHEN Trans = @trans1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        END,
    Trans1 = SUM(CASE WHEN Trans = @trans1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    Trans2 = SUM(CASE WHEN Trans = @trans2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM DS
WHERE Trans IN (@trans1, @trans2)
GROUP BY ID
```

**RESULT**

```
ID          PairCount   Trans1      Trans2
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           0           1           0
2           2           2           2
3           0           1           0
```